# One-to-many or many-to-many for Ads-Tags relation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am developing a Spring Boot app in which I have Ads, and when a user is creating a new Ad, he needs to give it a few tags (we need to filter ads through that tags later). I have fixed list of those Tags and I currently have 20 Tags (that number may change later). I made a many-to-many relationship(with join table) but I don't know is that a good choice because I am struggling now with creating ads.

This is my Ad entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name= "ads")
public class Ads {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tags_ads",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ads_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tags_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Tag> adsTags;
```

And this is my Tag entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Tags")
public class Tag {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
        
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "adsTags")
    private Set<Ads> ads;
        
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Set<Ads> getAds() {
        return ads;
    }
    public void setAds(Set<Ads> ads) {
        this.ads = ads;
    }
}
```

But when I want to create ad I have some errors regarding tags. So, I would like to know is many-to-many good choice for this situation or maybe I need to use one-to-many?

Comment: Since each tag can be assigned to multiple ads and each ad may have multiple tags, yes,, the `many-to-many` relationship is the proper choice here.

Comment: can you provide your service code where you saving entity? I think your many to many relation must be fetchType Eager in your situation.